# How to display my angular modules' views as the index page in MEAN.JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I realised that the index page is index.server.view.html, but it only contains the following content:

```
{% extends 'layout.server.view.html' %}

{% block content %}
    <section data-ui-view></section>
{% endblock %}
```

I want to display one of my angular module view as my index page with the use of the corresponding angular controllers and services.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question? You posted the code from a single file, which doesn't have any angular code in it except for `data-ui-view`.  It contains a reference to another file which you didn't include, which probably has the remainder of your code, including the angular bits in it......

Comment: layout.server.view.html contains the main layout of the whole website, it basically setup the <head> tag for the app

Comment: right, so again, what is your question? "I want to display one of my angular module" isn't a question, and not showing where any of the angular pieces are at (`ng-app`, `ng-controller`, etc.) doesn't help clarify what it is you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if it is a stupid question, but I have just found the answer.

The content of the index page is located at `public/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html`, which is the route `/` set in `public/modules/core/config/core.client.routes.js`.

Now, I can modify the home.client.view.html to display my data and use my angular controller

Comment: Yes, this is correct. Your Angular `*.client.routes.js` files will basically connect your "urls" to your html documents.